# squid configuration change to accept http request on LAN

Tags: squid, dansguardian

installed squid + dansguardian to block adult content on my linux (ubuntu 12.10) . everything worked fine. it has blocked as expected . now the problem is i am also running an apache server for my LAN . ( kind of website ) but when accessing it via 192.168.0.1 , it says squid has blocked the connection , this is the exact error

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http: //192.168.0.16/

Connection to 192.168.0.16 failed.

The system returned: (113) No route to host

The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.
```

before configuring the squid it was working fine .
 what changes in the squid.conf i have to make .
i tried

```
   acl Safe_ports 80

   allow_all Safe_ports
```

( i want to know how i can configure it again to listen HTTP request from LAN )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No route to host" suggests that something else happened while you were configuring Squid. If you log into the machine running Squid (presumably 192.168.0.1), can you ping 192.168.0.16 from there?